# EJB:011224 Unable to bind the interface. Another EJB has already bound an interface to that name

Tags: oracle-adf, weblogic12c

I am having a subject line issue with my ADF application. It works OK on WLS 10.3.6 env, but fails on WLS 12c (12.2.1.3).
Some background. I have model, reusable and ADF UI projects. The model has services part, which is deployed from the application menu. The same model project is a dependency for reusable and ADF UI project. The services part deploys OK, but when I deploy the ADF UI project, it fails with EJB:011224.
Per Oracle Note

javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: [EJB:011224]Unable to bind the interface - JNDI naming collision occurs when two separate applications, EAR and WAR, have the same exact EJB (Doc ID 1642388.1)

Removing the bean class from the WAR file is the correct way to fix this issue. The war gets successfully deployed after ear deployment
OR
Setting metadata-complete="true" flag in web.xml will not process any annotations, and deployment succeeds.
But these workarounds did not help.

Comment: If the EAR has an EJB module and the WAR has EJBs in it that are the same then that is most likely where your naming conflict is coming from. Since it is an Enterprise application it would be more appropriate that your WAR project use the EJBs that are packaged in the EAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I indicated this is a "feature" of WLS 12c version, the project works OK with WLS 11g.
The application itself is divided into several projects, one is an ADF Model project, which is deployed as an ADF Library (JAR) and as an ADF Application (EAR), which contains the web services.
As ADF Library does not allow customizations, to avoid the mentioned project you have to create a usual JAR deployment profile and remove all the classes which are related to the services part, to do so go to Deployment profile->Project output -> Filters and uncheck the classes

Comment: I am having same issue. What kind of JAR did you use? If I don't use ADF Library, I cannot see the data control for the application module.